# R: use values in existing columns to index position of values in another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

(Apologies if duplicate: I've had a look and can't find this question asked).

I'm trying to create a new column in a dataframe1 which will be based on the values in dataframe2. For each row, the index of the value I want from dataframe2 is specified in two columns: *lineno* is row, and *position* is column.

df1:

```
      lineno position
1      1        1
2      1        9
3      2       11
4      2        3
5      2       17
```

This seemed straightforward; I thought I could do it with:

```
df1 %>% mutate(new_col = df2[lineno, position])
```

But this seems to return the entire dataframe? For each row in `df1$new_col` the result is `<data.frame [1,000 × 5,714]>`

Any ideas?

Comment: I think `df2[cbind(lineno, position)]` should work... cannot test without a df2 example, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `dplyr` you can adding `rowwise`

```
df1 %>%rowwise()%>%  mutate(new_col = df2[lineno, position])
```

Comment: Great easy fix! Didn't realize that's what was missing :)

Comment: FYI: `rowwise` can have horrible performance with larger datasets.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you add `purrr` to your repertoire:

```
df1 <- read.table(text='      lineno position
1      1        1
2      1        9
3      2       11
4      2        3
5      2       10', header=TRUE)
df2 <- mtcars

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>% mutate(
  new_col = map2(lineno, position, ~ df2[.x,.y])
)
#   lineno position new_col
# 1      1        1      21
# 2      1        9       1
# 3      2       11       4
# 4      2        3     160
# 5      2       10       4
```

You can be "safer" if you use one of the specific `map2_` variants, such as `map2_dbl`.